# STOPPING Timer App - Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer

I am trying to make a timer app. I am fine with Play button but I couldnt get Pause button working. I have seen some tutorials on Timer Apps and most of them have only used: [timer invalidate] code for that method that solely stops the time that is currently being shown in the label (display). Even that code doesn't work for me so I tried doing this which makes kinda more sense but still, of no luck.

```
@implementation ViewController

int timerCounter=0;
NSTimer *timer;
NSString *label;
BOOL isPaused=NO;

-(IB Action) playButton:(id)sender{

     [timer invalidate];
     isPaused=NO;
     timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector: @selector(tick) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(IBAction) pauseButton:(id)sender{

     [timer invalidate];
     isPaused=YES;

     label=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",timerCounter];
    _labelTimer.text=label;
}

-(void) tick{

    if (isPaused==NO){
       timerCounter++;
    }

   label=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",timerCounter];
  _labelTimer.text=label;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more precise about what is not working?

Comment: Using global variables is not a good practice, make then properties.

Comment: Pause button. Whenever I press that button, it doesn't have any effect on the timer. The timer keeps increasing by one.

Answer (score 1):

The NSTimer API do not have any method for pausing. What is available is either fire or invalidate. About your code, You are using global variables - not a good practice, most probably the instance of timer you are calling is not the same, remove them and add a property in the class extension in .m instead:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer * timer;
```

you then address that property with self.timer.
If this does not help, check if the button call the method when you press it.

Comment: The current value of the timer is stored in timerCounter variable already.

Comment: Ok I did add a property in h.file and called it in m.file using self.timer.
And yeah it doesn't seem to make any difference still. How do you if the button calls the pauseMethod? By setting breakpoints?

Comment: Can you update the new code you have, yes set a breakpoint when you invalidate the timer and see what are the instances you pause.

Comment: @EmilDo Do not add the property in the header (.h) file unless it needs to be public. Instead add it in a Class Extemsion in the implementation (.m) file. In general do not put anything that is not explicitly designed to be public in the header file.

Comment: Of course, you are right, i just assumed that he will be passing some of these values from another controller, I updated my answer.